# why this equality involving matrix holds true?

Tags: matrices, inequality, matrix-calculus, positive-semidefinite, matrix-norms

I am studying Lemma 11 of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04426.pdf)
I am having difficulty understanding on the last step, in particular, I have two questions:

**The first question (1)** On the first equality of the last step on page 15, the authors use
$$u^TSu=u^T(nI_n-zz^T+\sigma [\text{ddiag}(\Delta zz^T-\Delta)])u$$
where $S=\text{ddiag(Azz^T)-A}$. and $\text{ddiag}$ is an operator that
sets all off-diagonal entries of
a matrix to zero.
But I don't understand why this is correct.

*My confusion is:*

I understand that

$$S=\text{ddiag(Azz^T)-A}=\text{ddiag}((zz^T+\sigma\Delta)zz^T)-zz^T-\sigma\Delta=\text{ddiag}((zz^T)(zz^T))+\sigma\text{ddiag}(\Delta zz^T)-\sigma\Delta-zz^T$$

As we can see that the first term $\text{ddiag}((zz^T)(zz^T))=nI_n$.

Thus I expect $\text{ddiag}(\Delta zz^T)-\Delta=\text{ddiag}(\Delta zz^T-\Delta)$.

But I don't see why this is true. According to the paper, the matrix $\Delta$ is not a diagonal-free matrix, thus the non-diagonal entries of the left-hand side $\text{ddiag}(\Delta zz^T)-\Delta$ should be $-\Delta_{ij}$, while the non-diagonal entries of the right-hand side should be zero.

Where am I wrong at?

**The second question (2)**
On the second last step, I don't understand why

(2a) $$u^T\text{ddiag}(\Delta zz^T)u\geq -\|u\|_2^2\|\Delta z\|_\infty$$

(2b) $$-\sigma u^T\Delta u\geq -\|u\|_2^2\|\Delta\|$$

Any insights would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For the first question you got it wrong; they do not say $\mathrm{ddiag}(\Delta zz^T) - \Delta = \mathrm{ddiag}(\Delta zz^T - \Delta )$; if you look at the second line of the equation you mention in p.15 they write $n ||u||^2_2+\sigma [u^T \mathrm{ddiag}(\Delta zz^T)u-u^T\Delta u]$. Its a very long work in LaTeX so they just misplaced a bracket.

Answer (score 1):

In the paper you have $A=zz^T+\sigma\Delta$ and $z\in\{\pm1\}^n$. Therefore $z^Tz=n$ and the matrix $zz^T$ has a diagonal of ones. It follows that
$$
\operatorname{ddiag}(zz^Tzz^T)
=\operatorname{ddiag}\big(z(z^Tz)z^T\big)
=\operatorname{ddiag}(nzz^T)
=nI_n
$$
and in turn,
\begin{align*}
S
&=\operatorname{ddiag}(Azz^T)-A\\
&=\operatorname{ddiag}\big( (zz^T+\sigma\Delta) zz^T\big) - (zz^T+\sigma\Delta)\\
&=nI_n+\sigma\operatorname{ddiag}(\Delta zz^T) - zz^T - \sigma\Delta.\\
\end{align*}
For your second question, note that $\operatorname{ddiag}(uv^T)=\operatorname{diag}(u\odot v)=\operatorname{diag}(v\odot u)$ in general, where $\odot$ denotes Hadamard (i.e., entrywise) product. Therefore
$$
u^T\operatorname{ddiag}(\Delta zz^T)u
\geq -\|u\|_2\|\operatorname{diag}(z\odot\Delta z)\|_2
= -\|u\|_2^2\|z\odot\Delta z\|_\infty.
= -\|u\|_2^2\|\Delta z\|_\infty.
$$
For your last question, the constant $\sigma$ is clearly missing. The expression $-\|u\|_2^2\|\Delta\|$ should read $-\sigma\|u\|_2^2\|\Delta\|$.